# How can I use underscore in name of dynamic object variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Website that I'm making is in two different languages each data is saved in mongodb with prefix _nl or _en
With a url I need to be able to set up language like that:

http://localhost/en/This-Is-English-Head/This-Is-English-Sub

My code look like that:

```
var headPage = req.params.headPage;
var subPage = req.params.subPage;
var slug = 'name';
var slugSub = 'subPages.slug_en';
var myObject = {};
myObject[slugSub] = subPage;
myObject[slug] = headPage;
console.log(myObject);
Site.find(myObject,
    function (err, pages) {
    var  Pages = {};

    pages.forEach(function (page) {
        Pages[page._id] = page;
    });

    console.log(Pages);

});
```

After console.log it I get following:

```
{ 'subPages.slug_en': 'This-Is-English-Sub',
  name: 'This-Is-English-Head' }
```

Is you can see objectname subPages.slug_en is seen as a String insteed of object name..
I know that javascript does not support underscores(I guess?) but I'm still looking for a fix, otherwise i'll be forced to change all underscores in my db to different character...

Edit:

The final result of console.log need to be:

```
{ subPages.slug_en: 'This-Is-English-Sub',
  name: 'This-Is-English-Head' }
```

Insteed of :

```
{ 'subPages.slug_en': 'This-Is-English-Sub',
  name: 'This-Is-English-Head' }
```

Otherwise it does not work

Comment: What do you want ? What is your problem ?

Comment: Underscores are fine, you just need to use the square bracket notation (as you have done) to read/write them. I suspect this has more to do with the fact you expect `pages.subPages["slug_en"]` to work and it doesnt

Comment: your code is working fine. what is the problem here?

Comment: Edit on my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are seeing `'subPages.slug_en'` (with string quotes) is because of the `.` in the object key, not the underscore.
Underscores are definitely supported in object keys without quoting.

Using `subPages.slug_en` (without string quotes) would require you to have an object as follows:

```
{ subPages: {slug_en: 'This-Is-English-Sub'},
  name: 'This-Is-English-Head' }
```

Which you could set with the following:

```
myObject['subPages']['slug_en'] = subPage;
```

Or simply:

```
myObject.subPages.slug_en = subPage;
```